# Android: In Place Editing Text in TextView on ButtonClick

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a TextView

```
TextView name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     //stuff
  }
});
```

Now, when clicking this TextView, it should "transform" to sort of an EditText, in which I can input my new text and complete the procedure by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have seen Options, in which another EditText provides the new text, or in which a static text is added.

In my case, however, I don't want any other popup or new View to appear.

I just want to set the new text in place, like an EditText, without the constant TextBox of an EditText.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: can you post an image what you would look like to be , from - to.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I can't find an image that describes what I want, but maybe I can explain it in another way: Imagine the title of this question is the TextView. Now when clicking this TextView with your mouse it transforms to a Textbox, which can read UserInput, just like a comment box. Now when hitting Enter (Or clicking add comment in this case), the title changes to the inserted user input.

Comment: Just create an EditText field, hide it when you start. Show your text view when you start. When a user touches it, grab the text, hide the text view and show editttext view.

Comment: How does the edittext appear, when a user touches the textview? Is it possible that the edittext appears in the same area where the textview once was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the textbox of the editable then you simply use this attribute to style the editbox

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

If you want to edit a textview you can use the following attribute

```
android:editable="true"
```

In actual code a TextView and an EditText is actually the same.
An Edit text is simply a textView with things added on.

Comment: Well I went with this solution. I made the background of the edittext transparent and added some other lines so that the keyboard wont appear each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could just extend de `EditText` class overriding the `getView` method to display as a `TextView`. This way you'd have an `EditText` and user would think it is in fact a `TextView`. However, I wouldn't recommend to do this because the view would be misleading and users wouldn't know the `TextView` is editable.

Comment: How would you do it, otherwise?

Comment: Perhaps the way you want to do it, but adding a `Button` to start editing like a pencil or whatever next to the `TextView`. Clicking that button would make the `TextView` editable.

Comment: If the `TextView`'s `editable` state is changed to true, will it appear as a `EditText`? Also nice idea.

Comment: No, instead add this `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`  to an `EditText` to look like a `TextView`.

Comment: @JavierEnríquez what would be the default background for an EditText, to revert the change once editing has finished?